# Funcion if para macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Quiero hacer una macro para obtener el año de produccion, tengo este codigo

```
Sub RPL_2018()


Range("F:K").Columns.Insert
Range("F1") = "Model Group"
Range("G1") = "Model Brand"
Range("H1") = "Model Description"
Range("I1") = "Mfg YrWk"
Range("J1") = "Mfg YrMth"
Range("K1") = "Mfg Yr"

Range("F2:F300") = "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2,7),MonthlyProd.xlsb!Models_List_Lookup[[#All],[Model 7D]:[User Interface]],2,0)"
Range("G2:G300") = "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2,7),MonthlyProd.xlsb!Models_List_Lookup[[#All],[Model 7D]:[User Interface]],4,0)"
Range("H2:H300") = "=VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2,7),MonthlyProd.xlsb!Models_List_Lookup[[#All],[Model 7D]:[User Interface]],5,0)"

Range("I2:I300") = "=CONCATENATE(""201"",MID(D2,3,3))"

Range("J2:J300") = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(I2),MonthlyProd.xlsb!MFG_YrMth[[#All],[YearWeek]:[YearMonth]],2,0)"
Range("K2:K300") = "=MID(J2,1,4)"
Range("U:U").Columns.Insert
Range("U1") = "Created YrMth"
Range("U2:U300") = "=TEXT(T2,""YYYYMM"")"

Range("W1") = "Text"
Range("X1") = "Problem"
Range("Y1") = "Unit Summary"
Range("Z1") = "TTFI"
Range("AA1") = "Yrs"
Range("AB1") = "Months"
Range("AC1") = "FW"
Range("AD1") = "To Transgroup"
Range("AE1") = "Repeated"

Range("W2:W300") = "=VLOOKUP(A2,SAP!B:N,13,0)"
Range("Y2:Y300") = "=CONCATENATE(E2,""" & Chr(10) & """,H2,""" & Chr(10) & """,D2,""" & Chr(10) & """,""Pur.date - "",TEXT(L2,""DD/MM/yyYY""),""" & Chr(10) & """,O2)"
Range("Z2:Z300") = "=ROUND(+T2-L2,0)"
Range("AA2:AA300") = "=DATEDIF(0,Z2,""y"")+1"
Range("AB2:AB300") = "=DATEDIF(0,Z2,""y"")*12+DATEDIF(0,Z2,""ym"")+1"
Range("AC2:AC300") = "=+WEEKNUM(T2)"
Range("AE2:AE300") = "=CONCATENATE(A2,"" - "",D2,"" - "",B2)"

Range("A1:AE300").Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("T:T").Columns.AutoFit
Range("Y:Y").WrapText = True
Range("AE:AE").WrapText = True
Range("Y:Y").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("Y1").WrapText = False
Range("AE1").WrapText = False

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$AE$300"), , xlYes).Name = "Replacemets"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Replacemets").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"

With Sheets("Tangela")
.Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End With
Range("A1").End(xlUp).Select

ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Todo funciona, el problema es que por ejemplo una unidad producida en el año 2019 tiene un numero de serie 4T94418309, lo que hace la formula Range("I2:I300") = "=CONCATENATE(""201"",MID(D2,3,3))" y me da como resultado 2019, ahora, con una unidad del 2020 donde el numero de serie es 4T04418309, corre la formula y me lanza como resultado 2010, porque es lo que concatena la formula, tengo planeado hacer un if con la condicion de que si el numero de serie empieza igual a "4T0" la formula sea la siguiente Range("I2:I300") = "=CONCATENATE(""202"",MID(D2,3,3))", pero al hacerlo no me aparecen, como podria solucionar eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto se podría de hacer de otras maneras mejores, pero tal cual lo tienes, simplemente sería hacer la fórmula dentro de un par de "SI":

```
"=IF(LEFT(D2,3)=""4T9"",CONCATENATE(""201"",MID(D2,3,3)),IF(D2,3)=""4T0"",CONCATENATE(""202"",MID(D2,3,3)),""No se ha definido.""))"
```

Si los 3 primeros carácteres de la izquierda de la celda D2 = 4T9 entonces concatenas con 201. Si los 3 primeros carácteres de la izqueirda de la celda D2 = 4T0 entonces concatenas con 202. Si ninguno se cumple "No se ha definido.".

Comment: Se armo Damian.